# Can't install ros warehouse for ros-noetic

Tags: c++, cmake, ros

I'm trying to use MongoDB with `rviz`. Hence, I tried compiling `warehouse_ros_mongo` after doing a `git-clone` to `~/catkin_ws/src folder`. However, the CMake fails anyone who has any idea on how to fix it. Otherwise, can some recommend a package to use with ROS in order to connect the MongoDB and interact with `rviz/moveit`.

Error encountered when compiling:

```sh
CMake Error at /home/zelix/catkin_ws/devel/share/warehouse_ros/cmake/warehouse_rosConfig.cmake:113 (message): Project 'warehouse_ros' specifies '/home/zelix/catkin_ws/src/warehouse_ros/include' as an include dir, which is not found. It does neither exist as an absolute directory nor in '/home/zelix/catkin_ws/src/warehouse_ros//home/zelix/catkin_ws/src/warehouse_ros/include'. Check the website 'http://ros.org/wiki/warehouse_ros' for information and consider reporting the problem. Call Stack (most recent call first): /opt/ros/noetic/share/catkin/cmake/catkinConfig.cmake:76 (find_package) warehouse_ros_mongo/CMakeLists.txt:15 (find_package)

-- Configuring incomplete, errors occurred! See also "/home/zelix/catkin_ws/build/CMakeFiles/CMakeOutput.log". See also "/home/zelix/catkin_ws/build/CMakeFiles/CMakeError.log".
```

Answer (score 0):

You’re missing an include directory from the package.

Do `mkdir /home/zelix/catkin_ws/src/warehouse_ros/include`

Comment: Actually, the package name is warehouse_ros_mongo. Though when i do a catkin_make it points to /home/zelix/catkin_ws/src/warehouse_ros/include . In fact it should be /home/zelix/catkin_ws/src/warehouse_ros_mongo/include